# Paypal - RestAPI - Sandbox Webhook not occurring

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-webhooks

Using my sandbox account with the RestAPI, I've created an invoice. My buyer account got the notification, I went to the link and paid it ok. There's notifications that I received payment.  However, no WebHook notification.

I added all events to my WebHook. When using the WebHook simulator, I get the POST to my API just fine. It's hosted by a Redmond based cloud provider and is https.

Under the WebHook Events link in the Sandbox section, it's showing no entries.

Where else can I go to investigate this?

Comment: I am also looking to implement WebHooks for the REST API since IPN doesn't work. Can you tell me if PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.CREATED is sent only upon execution of the payment or is it sent 3 times, once upon created, once on approved and once on executed? I ask because I am hoping Webhooks will allow me to know when the client authorizes a payment (in case I miss the callback). If it is only sent upon execution of the payment then it is essentially worthless for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[list all your registered webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#list-all-webhooks) use following with your actual access-token

```
  curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>'
```

in the response, you should be able to find out what exactly were in the system for your webhooks, if not, did you [created the webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-webhook) as document says?

```
curl -v POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>' \
-d '{
    "url": "https://www.yeowza.com/paypal_webhook",
    "event_types": [
        {
            "name": "PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.CREATED"
        },
        {
            "name": "PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.VOIDED"
        }
    ]
}'
```

Comment: Hi Allen, I configured as suggested, still unable to get an event to my web hook in sandbox

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check what are the funding sources used to create the payment. Currently webhook only sends the notification if the customer pays with an echeck. So far there are no notifications sent if the payment is made with other funding sources. Also, you may need to check the events that you have chosen. Based on this [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/) , only authorizations are currently supported.

Comment: Thanks for that link - but I don't see on there where it's limited on which events it will sends notifications for. The configuration tool shows various different types.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see on the RestAPI documentation azlankasim is correct saying that only some fundings are supported.

On the bottom of the page it says that only PayPal authorizations are supported.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/

"Note: Only PayPal authorizations are currently supported. Direct credit card transactions are not yet supported. We are actively working on adding more event types."

Have you tried to test using PayPal payment, to check if this is the problem?

Comment: In sandbox mode, I have tested paying an invoice using a test buyer's PayPal balance; as far as I can tell, there was still no webhook event triggered.

Comment: Have you tried listing your webhooks through /v1/notifications/webhooks ? If they're all there, try simulating one with /v1/notifications/simulate-event, and if that doesn't work then perhaps it's a good idea to contact PayPal tech support directly, since you're using their API as intended. It also might be worthwhile to check the logs on your server where you set to receive the postback - perhaps the logs there may tell you if something came through, but may not have been processed properly.

Comment: I am able to simulate events, and they work as intended and arrive properly at my server. Except for these manually simulated events, I do not see any requests at all in my logs to the hook receiver. I would love to contact PayPal support about this but I'm having a hard time getting ahold of them; their dev support site seems to think that StackOverflow *is* the support channel. :-(